# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I have problem of deploy rails application through Capistrano, below are the logs for the deployment process.

```
DEBUG [9d92ed37] Command: cd /var/www/PROJECT-NAME/releases/20160408041814 && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.1 do bundle install --path /var/www/PROJECT-NAME/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
DEBUG [9d92ed37]    bash: line 1:  2027 Killed                  /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.1 do bundle install --path /var/www/PROJECT-NAME/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as root@X.X.X.X: bundle exit status: 137
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: bash: line 1:  2027 Killed                  /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.1 do bundle install --path /var/www/PROJECT-NAME/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 137
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: bash: line 1:  2027 Killed                  /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.1 do bundle install --path /var/www/PROJECT-NAME/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as root@X.X.X.X: bundle exit status: 137
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: bash: line 1:  2027 Killed                  /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.2.1 do bundle install --path /var/www/PROJECT-NAME/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
dipak@Dipak:/dipak/sites/PROJECT-NAMEs-Latest$
```

Unable to understand the what is the solution for this. before it's working fine but suddenly it's giving me error.

If there is problem with storage then I have lot's space.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            230M     0  230M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  616K   49M   2% /run
/dev/vda1        20G  8.4G   11G  46% /
tmpfs           245M  4.0K  245M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           245M     0  245M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add 2GB of swap memory to your linux server
I used htop for review ram while capistrano is running, in my server with 4GB of ram, this was full out. So, I added 2GB of swap and capistrano used that site.
https://hk.godaddy.com/en/help/add-memory-swap-centos-17328

Answer (score 0):

A failure at **SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError:** means that the prod server can't process your request correctly. Try installing **nodejs** and **yarn** on the user you deploy to.  Docker simplifies the stack by abstracting much of the production configuration from the developer.

```
cap production deploy --trace

sudo apt-get install nodejs

curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install yarn
```

`yarn --version`